# XPath, set position and contains simultaneously

Tags: xpath

Please clarify how to create xpath with the next 'structure':

```
text()[position = 1 and contains(text(), 'xxx')]
```

I've tried

```
text()[1]/text()[contains(text(), 'xxx')]
```

but wasn't successful

Comment: What do you mean by position?

Comment: I meant block like [1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`position` is a function, not a node test.

So you need to use:

```
text()[position() = 1 and contains(., 'xxx')]
```

Or faster

```
text()[1][contains(., 'xxx')]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm a new to xpath, so didn't know I can use serveral [] conditions. Now it works.

Comment: But `text` nodes don't have any child nodes so neither `text()[position() = 1 and contains(text(), 'xxx')]` nor `text()[1][contains(text(), 'xxx')]` seem meaningful to me. It should be `text()[position() = 1 and contains(., 'xxx')]` respectively `text()[1][contains(., 'xxx')]`, no?

Comment: @MartinHonnen: you are right. I just copied the conditions without reading them...